# SQL Table: How to shift entire column up, while leaving others alone

Tags: php, mysql, database

Suppose I have the following sample table:

```
col1      col2      col3
-------------------------
7         12        0
3         34        0.01
9         62        0.5
2         88        1.1
8         20        2.4
1         18        2.8
```

I am trying to erase rows **only** from col2 and col3 anywhere where values in col3 are below a certain value, and shift the remaining values up in those columns, while leaving col1 alone. For example, if I set my col3 minimum value to 0.5, my new table should look like this:

```
col1      col2      col3
-------------------------
7         62        0.5
3         88        1.1
9         20        2.4
2         18        2.8
```

Note that the values in col1 are not sequential, and have remained in the same order, but the table has become shorter by the number of rows that were deleted.

The solutions I have found so far all seem to be based on the values in col1 being sequential. For example [something like this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/47097/how-can-i-shift-certain-column-values-to-different-rows-in-an-existing-table). I have also looked at the example provided [here](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=112129) but it does not seem to be quite what I am trying to do, but I could be wrong.

Not trying to get anyone to do this for me, just trying to get some guidance and advice. Even if it's just some some links to appropriate resources I would be quite grateful.

Thanks!

Comment: There's no 'up' here. :-(

Comment: is your value is stored in column are sorted way??

Comment: @Strawberry To clarify, what I mean is once the top few values in col2 and col3 are removed, the remaining values of those two columns are "moved up" to to fill the empty space. Apologies if this was unclear from the title.

Comment: @AmitGaud I am not sure I understand your question. Can you please clarify?

Comment: I know what you mean. I mean there is no 'up'!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An auto-incrementing id with no gaps renders the problem fairly trivial. An ascending id *with* gaps would work too, but it adds a layer of complexity...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,col1 INT NOT NULL
,col2 INT NOT NULL
,col3 DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,7,12,0),
(2,3,34,0.01),
(3,9,62,0.5),
(4,2,88,1.1),
(5,8,20,2.4),
(6,1,18,2.8);

SELECT b.id
     , b.col1
     , a.col2
     , a.col3
  FROM 
     ( SELECT @i:=@i+1 i
            , col2
            , col3 
         FROM my_table
            , (SELECT @i:=0) vars 
        WHERE col3 >= 0.5 
        ORDER 
           BY id
     ) a
  JOIN my_table b
    ON b.id = a.i;
+----+------+------+------+
| id | col1 | col2 | col3 |
+----+------+------+------+
|  1 |    7 |   62 | 0.50 |
|  2 |    3 |   88 | 1.10 |
|  3 |    9 |   20 | 2.40 |
|  4 |    2 |   18 | 2.80 |
+----+------+------+------+
```

Comment: Do you think that without creating another table, this is achievable?

Comment: Table? yes. Column? no.

Comment: @Ankit Bajpai -the table here is only to reproduce the answerer's solution, to replicate your schema. You as the OP don't have to that. The unique `id` is necessary.

Comment: I see what you are getting at here. I really should have included that auto-incrementing id, that makes things a lot more clear. I think what I will do is use this idea but I may go with a two-table option. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Alright so thanks to some useful input/discussion/comments from @Strawberry and @Ankit Bajpai I decided to do this using a slightly more crude 2-table method. I realize that this may not be the most efficient way to go about this but this was quick, easy, and got things working exactly as I wanted them to.

Here is the breakdown of what I did in painful detail:

First, I gave my original table a primary auto-incrementing id column (which I really should have done in the first place):

```
ALTER TABLE table1 ADD id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

This changed my original table structure to this:

```
col1      col2      col3      id
--------------------------------
7         12        0         1
3         34        0.01      2
9         62        0.5       3
2         88        1.1       4
8         20        2.4       5
1         18        2.8       6
```

Then, after creating another table (table2) with an identical table structure as table1, I populated table2 with the data I wanted to keep from table1 like this:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (col1, col2, col3)
  SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM table1 WHERE col3 >= 0.5
```

This gave me the following result in table2:

```
col1      col2      col3      id
--------------------------------
9         62        0.5       1
2         88        1.1       2
8         20        2.4       3
1         18        2.8       4
```

And then, to finish things off, I updated col1 in table2 with the values in col1 in table1 using my new id as the condition:

```
UPDATE table2
  SET table2.col1 = table1.col1
  WHERE table2.id=table1.id
```

And this gives me exactly what I need in table2:

```
col1      col2      col3      id
--------------------------------
7         62        0.5       1
3         88        1.1       2
9         20        2.4       3
2         18        2.8       4
```

Once again, I realize that this may not be the most efficient way to go about this but this was quick, easy, and got things working exactly as I wanted them to.